# search view coming along with toolbar

Tags: java, android

I'm using search in my toolbar menu when I'm clicking search icon toolbar is coming in top below that search view appearing. I want only search view. my search click:

```
else if (id == R.id.search) {
        if (Connectivity.isConnected(MainActivity.this)) {
//                removePIP();
//                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
SearchActivity.class);
//                intent.putExtra("type", "search");
//                startActivityForResult(intent, activityRequestCode);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("type", "search");
            SearchFragment searchFragment =new SearchFragment();
            searchFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, searchFragment, SearchFragment.class.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack("SearchFragment").commit();

//                    .add(R.id.youtube_player, youtubeFragment)

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, 
R.anim.exit_to_left);

        } else {
            Utils.showNoConnectionToast(MainActivity.this);
        }
//        } else if (id == R.id.voice_search) {
//            if (Connectivity.isConnected(MainActivity.this)) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
SearchActivity.class);
//                intent.putExtra("type", "voicesearch");
//                startActivityForResult(intent, activityRequestCode);
//                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, 
R.anim.exit_to_left);
//            } else {
//                Utils.showNoConnectionToast(MainActivity.this);
//            }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove toolbar from your `SearchFragment` class using this,

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    private Toolbar toolbar; // declare toolbar in fragment

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container
            , @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container);
        toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar); // initialise toolbar
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // set visibility gone
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // make it visible when your fragment stops
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: i dnt wnt to hide the visibilty i wnt to override search over toolbar.